# Is it possible for the bargeIn parameter to allow the caller to interrupt the Twilio TTS?

Tags: twilio, text-to-speech, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Currently responding with a long(ish) `<Say>` followed by a `<Gather bargeIn="true">` doesn't stop Twilio TTS from finishing the `<Say>` and listening to the user's speech.  Is this not supported?

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="Polly.Matthew-Neural" language="en-US">This is a whole lot of instructions to give the person on the other end of the call. etc...</Say>
    <Gather input="speech" action="https://myserver/api/v1/webhooks/twilio" timeout="3" speechTimeout="auto" language="en-US" bargeIn="true" speechModel="phone_call" enhanced="true"></Gather>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `<Gather>` has to wrap the `<Say>` [according to the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) like this:

```xml
<Gather>
    <Say>
        Please enter your account number, followed by the pound sign
    </Say>
</Gather>
<Say>We didn't receive any input. Goodbye!</Say>
```